# PHP laravel database

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php 
$__currentLoopData = $orders; 
$__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); 
foreach($__currentLoopData as $order): 
   $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); 
   $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
<?php

$checkout=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table("product_checkout")
->where("ord_id",$order->ord_id)->first();

$date=\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$checkout
->payment_date);
$date->addDay(7);

?>
```

I am using this query to get payment date but face the error:
Trying to get property of non-object

> (View:
>   /home/fivepkfg/slmarket.lk/local/resources/views/order_notifications.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /home/fivepkfg/slmarket.lk/local/resources/views/order_notifications.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /home/fivepkfg/slmarket.lk/local/resources/views/order_notifications.blade.php)
>
> in a23b800208135141a4d361f9e28ed9a54222c130.php (line 119)

Comment: Post the Loop codes and the Query chains so we can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your query is returning null result, so that property `->payment_date` is called on a null `$checkout` variable.

Ensure that your Query parameters value are OK and that a result exists. In some case where no checkout is allowed you may need to check for Null before further operations :

```
@if($checkout)
    <?php
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$checkout->payment_date);
    $date->addDays(7);
    ?>
@endif
```

And the method of `Carbon` is `->addDays(7)`;